# mysql : Passing sql statement as parameter in stored procedure to execute it

Tags: mysql, oracle12c, mysql-error-1064

Please help me with my query:
I have below mentioned stored procedure in oracle and I need to convert it to MySQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EAMP.EXEC_DDL (SQLSTMT VARCHAR2) AUTHID DEFINER
is
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT
END EXEC_DDL;
/
```

This is what I have created in MySQL (version 5.7):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EXEC_DDL;
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLSTMT VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
set @sql = SQLSTMT;
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
EXECUTE STMT;
deallocate prepare STMT;
END;
```

but it is giving me below mentioned error:

```
20:08:43  START Executing, Database Connection: EAMP DEV MYSQL Database Type: MYSQL Catalog: ampd01 Schema: null
20:08:47  INFO  Physical database connection acquired for: EAMP DEV MYSQL  
20:08:47  WARNING  [DROP - 0 rows, 0.994 secs]  OK. No rows were affected
SQLWarning: 
Code: 1305 SQL State: 42000 --- PROCEDURE ampd01.EXEC_DDL does not exist  
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EXEC_DDL;
20:08:48  FAILED  [CREATE - 0 rows, 1.245 secs]  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 
42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' 
at line 4  
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLSTMT VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
set @sql = SQLSTMT;
20:08:49  FAILED  [PREPARE - 0 rows, 1.243 secs]  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 
42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'NULL' at line 1  
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
20:08:51  FAILED  [EXECUTE - 0 rows, 1.253 secs]  [Code: 1243, SQL State: 
HY000]  Unknown prepared statement handler (STMT) given to EXECUTE  
EXECUTE STMT;
20:08:52  FAILED  [DEALLOCATE - 0 rows, 1.255 secs]  [Code: 1243, SQL State: 
HY000]  Unknown prepared statement handler (STMT) given to DEALLOCATE 
PREPARE  
deallocate prepare STMT;
20:08:53  FAILED  [END - 0 rows, 1.253 secs]  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1  
END;
20:08:55  END Execution 6 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, 
exec/fetch time: 7.243/0.000 secs   [1 successful, 1 Warnings, 5 errors]*/
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

With semicolons in the body of the procedure, we need to change the statement delimiter for the session.

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo() 
BEGIN
  SELECT NOW();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

With that, the semicolon that appears in the stored procedure does not end the `CREATE` statement. And we can change the statement delimiter back to semicolon when we're done.

---

*EDIT*

Here's an analysis of the reported output:

This statement

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EXEC_DDL;
```

completed successfully, raising a warning "procedure does not exist"

The next statement executed was this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLSTMT VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
set @sql = SQLSTMT;
```

MySQL returned a syntax error; which is expected behavior, because that's not a valid SQL statement. The next statement executed:

```
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
```

returned an error, because `@sql` evaluates to `NULL`.  The next statement executed

```
EXECUTE STMT;
```

failed because STMT isn't a valid statement handle. (Because the PREPARE failed.)

---

We don't want to execute the `SET` and `PREPARE` as separate statements, we want those to be part of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

The problem is that the semicolon character is the statement terminator; we need to change the statement terminator to be something else, to some string that doesn't appear in the body of the `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Here's a demonstration using the MySQL Command Line Client

```
# mysql --defaults-extra-file=/opt/mysql/scripts/config.cnf --database test

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS foo $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS foo $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT NOW();
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL foo();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-06-13 13:33:33 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
```

Comment: i tried defining statement terminator also, and the code looks like this:     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EXEC_DDL;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLSTMT                            VARCHAR           (4000))
BEGIN
set @sql = SQLSTMT;
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
EXECUTE STMT;
deallocate prepare STMT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: but it gave me below mentioned error msg: 12:20:44  FAILED  [DELIMITER - 0 rows, 1.264 secs]  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLS' at line 1  
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`ampd_own`@`%`
PROCEDURE `ampd01`.`EXEC_DDL`(in SQLSTMT VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
set @sql = SQLSTMT;

Comment: 12:20:46  FAILED  [PREPARE - 0 rows, 1.263 secs]  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1  
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
12:20:47  FAILED  [EXECUTE - 0 rows, 1.248 secs]  [Code: 1243, SQL State: HY000]  Unknown prepared statement handler (STMT) given to EXECUTE  
EXECUTE STMT;
12:20:48  FAILED  [DEALLOCATE - 0 rows, 1.248 secs]  [Code: 1243, SQL State: HY000]  Unknown preparedstatementhandler (STMT) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE  
deallocate prepare STMT;

Comment: Whatever client is being used to execute these SQL statements appears to not be recognizing the `DELIMITER` statement. Answer modified to give a further demonstration using the MySQL Command Line client. (No information is  given in the question as to the actual database client or library being used.).

Comment: thank you. I am able to fix this issue. I used @ in front of delimiter and it worked like this: @DELIMITER %%%;